# SQLAlchemy commit primaryjoin column

Tags: python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

I Have two tables "CashDoc" and "Entry".

```
class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'journal_entries'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    credit = Column('credit', String)
    debit = Column('debit', String) 
    amount = Column('amount', Float)

    property = sql.Column('property', sql.types.JSON, default={}, server_default='{}')
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now(), server_default=text('now()'))
    edited = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('now()'), onupdate=text('now()'))
```

CashDoc has column "entries" with primaryjoin

```
class CashDoc(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cash_docs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    amount = Column(Float)

    entries = relationship(Entry, primaryjoin="foreign(Entry.property.op('->>')('cashdoc_id')).cast(Integer) == CashDoc.id.cast(Integer)")

    created = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('now()'))
    edited = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('now()'), onupdate=text('now()'))
```

Then I can create CashDoc and Entries like this

```
new_doc = CashDoc(params)
new_doc.entries.append(Entry('62', '50', new_doc.amount))
```

But after session.commit() `property` field has only id. Not json.
How can I save `property` in this format `{'cashdoc_id': id}` ?

Comment: `default=datetime.now()` should probably be `default=datetime.now`. You're setting the default to what ever time you created your model class at.